# url of custom theme not showing up with page.tpl

Tags: 7, theming, uri

I've a custom theme. page.tpl has the html markup for my template. And I created some paths like 'about-us', 'terms' via my custom module.

Now, my problem is when I access the above defined paths. They are just showing up the contents defined in the callback function.

What I've to do if I want to show the contents in the content region of my page.tpl

Please help me.

----- THIS IS FIXED NOW :: THANKS FOR YOUR HELP -------

Comment: Have you read [Theming Guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme‎)? Just asking...

Comment: how did you define your callbacks? Did you generate render arrays and rendered them?

Comment: Thanks @xurshid29 it was my very careless mistake instead of returning the contents of the function actually I printed them. Now I solved the problem, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Mołot it's just my mistake. I fixed it now by returning the contents (I tried printing previously)

Comment: @GokulGopalaKrishnan Please post your solution as an answer, then :)

Comment: Seriously? But actually there is no solution, the question is a bad one, So I'm deleting this question :)

Comment: @GokulGopalaKrishnan noooo, not really. First, it's a mistake that can realistically happen and asking isn't THAT bad, and second, deleting can lead to question ban when you have no upvoted questions.

Comment: Ohhhh, thanks a lottt @Mołot I'm answering my question now :) thank you again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for helping. I changed the contents of the callback function, print to return. It solved the problem.